# How to check elements in a random numbers list in C

Tags: c++, loops, automation, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I have a list of randomly generated 50 numbers. If i want to check the list to see if there are any numbers above 15 in it, how it should be done on Arduino IDE?

This is how i am doing it, but not working:

```
 for (int x = 0 ; x < 50 ; x++)  
  {
    if(list[x]>=15) 
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);     //turn LED on 
    if(list[x]<15) 
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);      //turn LED off 
  }
```

Please help!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: I suspect that the loop is running so fast the led barely flickers (if at all), but if the numbers are indeed random sometimes the last list entry should be >= 15 and that should cause the led to stay lit.  I think we need more context.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I mean even though the numbers are above 15, it is not turning LED on.

Comment: `bool greater= false; 
for (int x = 0 ; x < 50 ; x++) if(list[x]>=15) greater = true; 
if(greater) digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); 
else digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);`

Comment: How are you able to determine that the LED doesn't get turned on, for a millisecond or so, before it gets turned off by the next number in the array (which is less than 15), for example?

Comment: @Dweeberly the context is that it is output from the sensor(the list). So it is either going to have numbers above 15 or all numbers below 15 (this is fixed). All i want to do is keep checking list, if there are numbers above 15 or not, if there are then switch LED on otherwise keep it off. Hope it helps.

Comment: You forgot the Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: your computer always does exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do. You told your computer: check each value of the array, if it's >= 15 turn the LED on, if it's <15 turn the LED off; repeat this logic for every value of the array. One after the other. And this is what your computer does, obediently following your instructions (so if the last number in the array is less than 15, the LED will be off, even if some earlier number was 20). If you want your computer to do something else, tell it what it should do, then.

Comment: I don't think you realize how fast that loop is running try, putting a sleep(100); in at the top or bottom of the loop.

Comment: sleep a while for each iteration, for example: sleep(1); // 1 second

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you are right, that is exactly what is happeing. That is what my question is, if i want to check list and see if there are numbers in it above 15 from any of 50 positions, turn LED on, if there is no number above 15 keep it off. Then comes next loop, check it again the same thing. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting you right, you want the led to be turned on if there is at least one element higher than 15.

In this case I would do something like this:

```
digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);      //turn LED off 
for (int x = 0 ; x < 50 ; x++)  
{
  if(list[x]>=15) 
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);     //turn LED on 
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: You got me right, this is exactly what I am trying to do. (want the led to be turned on if there is at least one element higher than 15.)
But I tried this code, it is keeping the LED on regardless of numbers being less than 15.

Comment: no value out of 50 is above 15, but LED in on. Do you have any other edit to it?

Comment: @hns did you perhaps forget to shut the led off before the for loop or ?  Code first shuts off led, then searches list, turning the led on (and stops looking) if it found a value greater than or equal to 15

Comment: Do you may have some errors in initialization of the ledPin?